# Inserting date in sql using vb.net dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem with date, when I insert a date into my sql database using datetimepicker keeps saying there is a problem converting string to date, I am using the following format dd/MM/yyyy I know that sql supports only MM/dd/yyyy and yyyy/MM/dd I want to compare it with function today, what I want is, is there any way to show the user this format dd/MM/yyyy and save in sql using this format MM/dd/yyyy and when comparing with function today I want to compare using this format MM/dd/yyyy???

I am using visual basic and sql server

Comment: " I know that sql supports only MM/dd/yyyy and yyyy/MM/dd" - erm, what? You are storing dates as dates right? And not strings?

Comment: Yeah as dates, if I use string I can't seem to compare I don't know why!?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

Let's put a couple things together. First:

> using datetimepicker

The DateTimePicker control has a [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) that gives you a VB DateTime value.

We also have this:

> You are storing dates as dates right? And not strings?
>
> Yeah as dates

Given those two things, **format doesn't matter**.  If you're *ever* trying to convert the DateTime value from your control to a string, you're doing it wrong.

I'll use a simple table with a single DateTime column as an example:

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@MyDateTimeColumn)", cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyDateTimeColumn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

At no point this code ever care what format is used for the DateTime, or try to treat it as a string at all. Code that tries to convert a DateTime value to a string hints that you're using a technique for building your sql queries that will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. *Don't do that.*

Comment: I know that the value of datetimepickers is DateTime, when I send it to database I take only date datetimepicker1.value.date, I tried your method I keep getting my dates in this format MM/dd/yyyy when viewing in datagridview only if I tried to take an appointment after a month from now, when choosing a date from this month shows this format dd/MM/yyyy when I compare with Today function.

Comment: Then the problem is selecting from the table, not inserting into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `DateTime` datatype in SQL, that you mention you did too, then in VB, try to convert your DateTimePicker date and convert it to DateTime Variable using `DateTime.TryParse` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx)

In this method your can define the incoming format/culture to use to try to convert `string` To `DateTime` type, and then use that variable as SQL Parameter to your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using datetime in your DB and you are sending a datetime from .net then there isn't problem. Maybe the problem is when you parse from datepicker, for example if you have '25/01/2014' it's January but if you try parse without specify the format you can get an error, .net could try to convert using the format 'mm/dd/yyyy'. If you use 'dd/mm/yyyy' you must use 
this:

```
    DateTime aDate = DateTime.ParseExact("25/01/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", null); //this is c#
```

No problem if your DB receives a datetime (sql type) and you send aDate, for example:

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("aCommand", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@aDateTimeParameter", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = aDate;
        }
    }
```